# Why do these two snippets produce different results?

Tags: c++, ruby

These two blocks of code theoretically should do the same thing just implemented in two different languages. But they produce completely different outputs.  The C++ produces the expected results while the ruby output is not even close.

### C++

```
unsigned long MEMO[10][10][21];

long generate(int a, int b, int l){
    if(MEMO[a][b][l] != 0){
        return MEMO[a][b][l];
    }
    if(l==0){
        return 1;
    }
    for(int i =0; i<=9-a-b; i++){
        MEMO[a][b][l] += generate(b, i, l-1);
    }
    return MEMO[a][b][l];
}

int main(){
    unsigned long sum = 0L;
    for(int i=1; i<10; i++){
        sum += generate(0,i,19);
    }
    printf ("Answer: %lu\n",sum);
    return 0;
}
```

### Ruby

```
MEMO = Array.new(10, Array.new(10, Array.new(21, 0)))

def generate a, b, l
  if MEMO[a][b][l] != 0
    return MEMO[a][b][l]
  end

  if (l==0)
    return 1
  end

  0.upto(9-a-b).each do |i|
    MEMO[a][b][l] += generate(b, i, l-1)
  end

  MEMO[a][b][l]
end

sum = 0
1.upto(9).each do |i|
    sum+= generate(0, i, 19)
end

puts sum
```

Ruby output: `72900000000000000000`

C++ output: `378158756814587`

Does anyone know why this might be?

**EDIT**:

Just in case this isn't clear, 378158756814587 IS the answer I want and it's what I expect the ruby code to produce. It is not integer overflow on the C++ side. 378158756814587 is still the answer when using a `unsigned long long`.

Comment: Check your compiler's documentation whether `unsigned long` is a 32-bit or a 64-bit integer. `72900000000000000000` requires 64 bit to represent. See if the answer changes when you use `unsigned long long` on the C++ side.

Comment: No it doesn't change when I use `unsigned long long` which is expected. The C++ answer is correct. The question is why is the ruby answer wrong.

Comment: Consider using `uint64_t` instead of `unsigned long` as it is evident that you wanted at least 64-bit math and `unsigned long` could be 32-bit or something else.

Comment: @Igor Tandetnik  It appears `72900000000000000000` requires 66 bits.

Comment: @chux as i've stated already, the c++ code works as expected. The problem, which i have already figured out a solution to, is in the ruby code.

Comment: @kristen The C++ code works expected on your platform, but not portable to others.  My recommendation was how to make it portable, not how to change your results.  Sorry if that was not clear.

Comment: @chux oh I see. Sorry, I didn't realize that was what you were implying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the problem. It's an error in my ruby code.

`MEMO = Array.new(10, Array.new(10, Array.new(21, 0)))`

If you were to print out the object ids of `MEMO[0]` and `MEMO[1]` you would find that they are the exact same. What I assumed `Array.new(10, Array.new)` would do is create an `Array` with 10 different `Array` objects inside of it. Instead it creates an `Array` of 10 references to the same `Array` object. 
By changing the first line to something like this:

```
MEMO = Array.new
10.times do
  MEMO << Array.new
  10.times do
    MEMO[-1] << Array.new(21, 0)
  end
end
```

or even simpler

`MEMO = Array.new(10) {Array.new(10) {Array.new(21) {0}}}`

It works perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's not exactly answer for you question, but...  if you replace first line by:

```
MEMO = Array.new(10) {Array.new(10) {Array.new(21) {0}}}
```

everything works fine. Both arrays looks the same, and for me there is no difference between them, but it seems that there is some little difference which causes your problem. Any ideas?